# Unix, copy file with other user permission

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions, sudo

I have file `/home/user1/file.txt` which I want to copy to `/home/user2/file.txt`. Neither user has any permission to other users home directory, but both user2 has permission to su user1. I administrate both accounts. How do I copy the file to user2 (with his permissions) as user1, when I know both users credentials?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the file to user2 (with his permissions) _as user1_"? Should the copied file have have user1's or user2's permissions?

Comment: user2's permissions, but the file is copied by user1

Answer (score 2):

I see two solutions :

Copy the file as root and then change the permission to user2

```
sudo cp /home/user1/file.txt /home/user2/
sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user2/file.txt
```

Or, copy the file from user1 to a folder where user 1 and user2 have permissions and then move it to /home/user2 with user2

user1 :

```
cp ~/file.txt /tmp
```

user2 :

```
mv /tmp/file.txt ~/file.txt
```